# IO File Read/Write Verilog

Tags: video, io, verilog, xilinx

I want to read a MPEG video file as stream of frames. I am using

```
$readmemh("centaur_1.mpg",mem);
```

but it does not seem to work as its designed to read ASCII code from text files that corresponds to the ranges of hex characters. Any suggestions on how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the `$fread()` system task. This will allow you to open a file in binary mode. Check the link below for an example:

- http://larc.ee.nthu.edu.tw/~lmdenq/doc/fileio.htm#File_Input_Functions